# Получить размер в байтах QByteArray.data()

Tags: c++, qt

Я подключил библиотеку C в C++, нужно вызвать функцию из этой библиотеки.

Функция принимает аргументы (char *str, size_t s).

У меня есть QByteArray с нужными данными, я получаю массив символов QByteArray.data(), а также нужно передать размер в байтах, размер получить не могу через sizeof(QByteArray.data()), так как возвращается указатель, а не сам массив char.

как я могу получить размер в байтах из QByteArray.data()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Открываем [мануал](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html), смотрим...

Как ни странно, `массив.size()`.

Comment: size() возвращает int. А конвертирование в size_t? А диапазон int хватит если QByteArray очень большой?

Comment: @AimonZ. Преобразование в `size_t` произойдет автоматически. У него похоже все конструкторы принимают размер в интах, поэтому размер не может не влезать в инт.